# How to take water-dispersed PEDOT:PSS and disperse it in an organic solvent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, materials, polymers

I am doing a science fair project on OLEDs. I am testing whether polypyrrole can be used as an emissive layer in a 2-layer OLED. The polypyrrole I am synthesizing is water soluble, and will be spin-coated onto ITO-coated glass substrate. I also need to spin-coat on a hole-injection layer (PEDOT:PSS). I can only seem to find it in what I believe to be water-dispersed form. This will cause obvious problems since both substances are water-soluble. I read on some informal message board that I could drop droplets of water-dispersed PEDOT:PSS into a hot organic solvent with a boiling point higher than water, boil off the water, and be left with organic-solvent dispersed PEDOT:PSS. That makes sense, I am just confused about what organic solvent to use. I believe it needs to have the properties of not dissolving the PEDOT:PSS, ITO, or the polypyrrole, and allow the PEDOT:PSS to become dispersed.

Here is [a link](http://www.heraeus-clevios.com/en/_technik/productdetail_1034017.aspx?psMarketId=1280&psApplicationId=1036289) to the PEDOT:PSS I am looking at:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Even if you switch to an organic solvent, if the polypyrrole is in water, it will perturb the PEDOT:PSS layer.**

Your best bet would be to use a poly-alkyl pyrrole or other conjugated polymer that's soluble in something that doesn't dissolve PEDOT:PSS.

Let's say you switch the solvent to DMF or DMSO and it dissolves the PEDOT:PSS. Then you spin-coat that new mixture onto ITO. Once you drop the aqueous solution of polypyrrole, it will dissolve the PEDOT:PSS.

I think you're looking at this the wrong way. Rather than trying to change the PEDOT:PSS (which will be tricky - PSS is anionic) you should consider changing your polymer. Alternatively, get rid of PEDOT:PSS and use another hole injection layer. (PEDOT:PSS is acidic and will etch the indium out of ITO.)

Comment: Funny story.. The original aim of my PhD was to find something more conductive, more transparent and less acidic than PEDOT:PSS.

Comment: OK, I will start searching for a method of synthesizing polypyrrole in a different solvent. Thanks!